# Eclipse wizard closes after pressing Enter key

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I've created an Eclipse wizard. It all works fine except that the wizard closes if I hit the Enter key.

I tried to handle that with a `TraverseListener`, but it didn't work.

I also tried `SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN`, but it didn't work.

```
new TraverseListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent event) {
                if(event.keyCode == SWT.CR){
  /** DO ANYTHING */

                    event.doit = false;
                }
            }
        };
```

The plugin is written in Java 1.7 in Eclipse Mars.

What is the best practice to handle issues like this?

Comment: What control have you added this listener to?

Comment: I added this listener to a textfield `txtUrl.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
   @Override
   public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent event) {
    if(event.keyCode == SWT.CR){
     /** DO ANYTHING */
     event.doit = false;
    }
    
   }
  }
  );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the traverse listener to the dialog shell and use `SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN`

```
getShell().addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
   @Override
   public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent event) {
     if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
        event.doit = false;
     }
   }
});
```